# Shapefile to PostGIS import generates django datetime error

Tags: django, shapefile, qgis, geodjango

Hi I'm trying to populate the PostGIS database of my Django application using a Shapefile. My models.py is the following :

```
class Flow(models.Model):
    # Primary key
    flow_id = models.AutoField("ID, flow identifier", primary_key=True)

    # Other attributes
    stime = models.DateTimeField("Start time")
    stime_bc = models.IntegerField("Year of start time before Christ")
    stime_unc = models.DateTimeField("Start time uncertainty")
    etime = models.DateTimeField("End time")
    etime_bc = models.IntegerField("Year of end time before Christ")
    etime_unc = models.DateTimeField("End time uncertainty")
    final_vers = models.BooleanField("1 if it's the final version, else 0",
                                default=False)
    com = models.CharField("Comments", max_length=255)
    loaddate = models.DateTimeField("Load date, the date the data was entered "
                            "(in UTC)")
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField("Publish date, the date the data become "
                           "public")
    cb_ids = models.ManyToManyField(Bibliographic)

    # Foreign key(s)
    fissure_id = models.ForeignKey(Fissure, null=True,
                           related_name='flow_fissure_id',
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cc_load_id = models.ForeignKey(Contact, null=True,
                           related_name='flow_cc_id_load',
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cc_pub_id = models.ForeignKey(Contact, null=True,
                          related_name='flow_cc_id_pub',
                          on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Override default table name
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'flow'
```

I want to add the features of my coulees.shp Shapefile into my database (more precisely in the flow table). The attribute table looks like this:

[Atribute table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm1Zv.png)

To do so I use the Django Layer Mapping:

```
import os
from django.contrib.gis.utils import LayerMapping
from .models import Flow

mapping = {'stime':'stime', 'stime_bc':'stime_bc', 'stime_unc':'stime_unc',  'etime':'etime', 'etime_bc':'etime_bc', 'etime_unc':'etime_unc', 'com':'com', 'loaddate':'loaddate', 'pubdate':'pubdate', 'geometry':'geometry'}

shp = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data', '/home/sysop/Coulees/coulees.shp')
)


def run(verbose=True):
    lm = LayerMapping(
        Flow, shp, mapping,
        transform=True
    )
    lm.save(verbose=True)
```

But when I try to run this function I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/mapobs/mapobs/app/load.py", line 30, in run
    transform=True
  File "/opt/mapobs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/utils      /layermapping.py", line 106, in __init__
    self.check_layer()
  File "/opt/mapobs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/utils/layermapping.py", line 256, in check_layer
    (ogr_field, ogr_field.__name__, fld_name))
django.contrib.gis.utils.layermapping.LayerMapError: OGR field "<class     'django.contrib.gis.gdal.field.OFTDate'>" (of type OFTDate) cannot be mapped to Django   DateTimeField.
```

Unfortunately, I can't find any useful documentation on the internet.

Comment: What happens if you try to map that field to Django DateField instead of DateTimeField? Unfortunately I can diagnose which model field is affected.

Comment: I can try but I need to store the time so it's a bit embarassing... If I just keep the stime attribute in the mapping list, I also have this error message

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `OFTDate` doesn't store the time. There is another field type `OFTDateTime`. My guess would be that `OFTDate` should be mapped to Django DateField, and `OFTDateTime` to Django DateTimeField.

Comment: @EvaChenYenSu do u get the solution. pls update it...me facing same issue